# Is there any way to override UILayout.prop tooltip?

Tags: python, node-editor, properties, pynodes

I have a collection on boolean properties I want to display in a node. `BoolVectorProperty` isn't really applicable because I want to be able to change the size of the array dynamically.

My issue is that when displaying a compact grid, there's no way to tell the user the index of a button. That is, I would like to override the tooltip of a `UILayout.prop` widget. If I set the `text`-kwarg to something nonempty, `icon_only` seems to be ignored.

My current code:

```py
class SequencerPosition(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    value: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Value")

class TriggerSequencer(Node):
    bl_idname = 'TriggerSequencerNode'
    bl_label = 'Trigger Sequencer'
    bl_width_min = 70.0

    sequence: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SequencerPosition, name="Sequence")

    def init(self, context):
        for i in range(16):
            self.sequence.add()

    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        grid = layout.grid_flow(row_major=True)
        for i, pg in enumerate(self.sequence):
            grid.prop(pg, 'value', icon_only=True)
```

results in this node:

[image: node UI in editor]

The tooltips are rather unhelpful, just saying "Value."

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dynamically re-annotate a pointer property**

[image]
*I forgot to select one*

Example below.  Note I've used Scene properties to illustrate the concept, as it's simpler to put together using simple panel template code and column flow to layout, than making custom nodes.  Pretty sure the same concepts apply.

The `Scene.foo_int` property unregisters re-annotates and re registers the propertygroup class.  The `init` call is emulated by calling the `rereg` update method.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty, PointerProperty, IntProperty


class SequencerPosition(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    __annotations__ = {}
    pass


def rereg(self, context):
    if getattr(SequencerPosition, "is_registered", False):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(SequencerPosition)
    SequencerPosition.__annotations__.clear()
    for i in range(self.foo_int):

        SequencerPosition.__annotations__[f"value{i}"] = BoolProperty(
            name=f"Value{i}",
            description=f"Do something with value {i}")

    bpy.utils.register_class(SequencerPosition)      
    bpy.types.Scene.foo = PointerProperty(type=SequencerPosition)  




class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        layout.prop(scene, "foo_int")
        grid = layout.column_flow(columns=8)
        for anno in SequencerPosition.__annotations__.keys():
            grid.prop(scene.foo, anno, icon_only=True)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.foo_int = IntProperty(min=0, max=32, update=rereg)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rereg(bpy.context.scene, bpy.context)
    register()
```

> Oh, and this won't really work if I have multiple instances of the
>   node, right?

Yes that's a catch on the dynamic registering, however can annotate the node with a maximum number, and only display so many based on a node int property

to demonstrate:

[image]

I've annotated the CustomNode with a max of 32 and used the int to set the layout

```
def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
    layout.label(text="Node settings")
    layout.prop(self, "my_int_prop")
    grid = layout.grid_flow(row_major=True, columns=4)
    for i in range(self.my_int_prop):
        grid.prop(self, f'value{i}', icon_only=True)
```

Comment: Appreciated. At least it's less complicated to do it like this than I thought, but I'm not sure if I'd rather just not have tooltips.

Comment: Oh, and this won't really work if I have multiple instances of the node, right?

Comment: Oops, yep.  Instead could register propertygroup class with max number of annotations, and only display based on length int.

Comment: I now have something like `__annotations__ = {f"step{i}": bpy.props.BoolProperty(name=f"Step {i}") for i in range(MAX_STEPS)}`. I still don't like the string indexing (I tried having integers as keys and Blender did a royal segfault), but this is a lot cleaner.

Comment: What string indexing?

Comment: The fact that I have to do `getattr(sequence, f"step{i}")` to address the steps programmatically, i.e. index them with strings "step0", "step1", ...

Comment: Would have segfaulted because the string is the name of the prop, which cannot be an integer... can learn some **facts** the hard way.  Could link to a collection such that it displays the step annotation (ie does the string indexing in the bg)  but hardly seems worth the hassle.  Been a pleasure helping.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I'd like for the code for registering the annotations be incorporated in your answer before accepting it.