# Custom/dynamic tooltips when hovering over properties in the UI

Tags: python, interface, properties, panel

I recently found out about the great "Paint Palettes" addon that comes with Blender but one thing that I really would have liked to see implemented is useful tooltips like name and/or values for when hovering over colors.

[image: color without useful tootip]
[image: select color without useful tootip]

I searched stackoverflow for a while and found out about dynamic tooltips for operators ([Changing tooltip for menu entries which use the same operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56727/changing-tooltip-for-menu-entries-which-use-the-same-operator)), but there doesn't seem to be (an easy) one for properties ([Is there any way to override UILayout.prop tooltip?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161529/is-there-any-way-to-override-uilayout-prop-tooltip))
I customized the addon to display names by adding this code in "class IMAGE_OT_select_color(Operator)" at line 440:

```
    @classmethod
    def description(cls, context, properties):
        pp = context.scene.palette_props
        color_name = pp.colors[properties.color_index].name
        return color_name
```

so now tooltip works and displays name of color when hovering over 'paint.select_color' operator. Yay, not bad for a noob programmer.
[image: select color with useful tootip]
How do I do the same for the color box above it which is a UILayout.prop in stead of a UILayout.operator?
If custom/dynamic tooltips for properties is not possible, is wrapping a property inside an operator and using that operator as a ui element an option and how can that be done in this situation?
Thanks in advance.