# How should I override tooltip of a UILayout.prop that exposes Blender's built-in property?

Tags: python, interface

For example, I'm exposing Blender's property that shows face orientation through `context.area.spaces[0].overlay.show_face_orientation` (which also doesn't correspond with Python Tooltip).

[image: Example]

But I want the `Show the Face Orientation Overlay.` tooltip to say something else. I only found **[one relevant question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161529/is-there-any-way-to-override-uilayout-prop-tooltip)**, but that's about dynamic custom property re-registration.

Only solution I could come up with is to make a new custom boolean property with its own description, and toggle built-in overlay using callback functions. I was hoping there would be a much simpler solution. Any ideas?